# data from text file in a form of text

Tags: scripting, cat

I have multiple directories (different names) which contain text files of he same name. I have to extract lines (numerical values) from those text files and create a single text file with a list of those values. The text file should be in the following format:

```
SubjectID  Metabolite_Cr_Conc  Metabolite_Cr_%SD   S/N   FWHM 
2012       2.900               58                  2     0.053
2901       4.1                 41                  1.5   0.56
2301       3.9                 29                  5.0   0.01
```

and so on.

I typically use `cat -n` for specific line numbers to get the data above  (line# for each metabolite are other numerical values are same across all subjectID).

Comment: Is that text the input or the expected output? You need to specify both the format of the input file, and the expected format of the output file, otherwise I'm afraid it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: "I have to extract lines (numerical values) from those text files ..."  I guess this means that you want to select a few lines, and not use the entire file.  How do you do that?  I don't understand what you're saying about `cat -n`, line number, and subjectID.  Please explain.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will help you for formatting output is `awk`.  For example:

```
date | awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}'
```

will give output in 10 character wide fields.

Comment: i think `date` is a very bad example for this use case.